# How to detect glittering on a surface OpenCV

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing

please help me with this as I am new to image processing. 
I have the following images, there is glitterings/powder on the surface of the hand. How do I go about detecting these things on the hand?

I have tried with detecting by getting 70% of the max Intensity in the image. However, only image one works the rest does not. Could anyone how to suggest any methods that I can use to perform the detection please.(any available codes to try with will be good) Thank you?

## Input Image 1: The only image that works with the above code

[image: Input Image 1: The only image that works with the above code]

## Input Image 2

[image: Input Image 2]

## Input Image 3

[image: Input Image 3]

## Desired Outcome

[image: Desire Outcome]

```
   //convert from bitmap to mat
    Mat mat = new Mat(bitmap1.getWidth(), bitmap1.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8UC3);
    Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap1, mat);

    Mat grayMat = new Mat();
    Imgproc.cvtColor(mat, grayMat, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

    //Log.d("TAGG","intensity" + mat.dump());

    int rows = mat.rows();
    int cols = mat.cols();
    double maxIntensity = Core.minMaxLoc(grayMat).maxVal;
    double minIntensity = 0.7 * maxIntensity;
    Log.d("TAGG", "intensity" + maxIntensity);

    Mat thresholdMat = new Mat();
    Imgproc.threshold(grayMat, thresholdMat, minIntensity, maxIntensity, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV);

    Bitmap outputBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(thresholdMat.cols(), thresholdMat.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Utils.matToBitmap(thresholdMat, outputBitmap);
```

Comment: Please actually include some images to your question to make this more clear.  Not having a visual representation of this will only lead to speculation rather than actual answers.  I've also removed the Python and Android Studio tags from your question.  Your question doesn't deal with either of these.

Comment: @rayryeng Image included